# AlarmManager - How to set a Notification to appear annually

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager, date

I want an notification to appear each year depending on the date entered (Birthday). I have everything else working bar how to set a notification annually. As you can see below I have changed the code to say "HERE" where the intervals go. There are intervals for days and I know I could multiply that by 365. But what happens if its a leap year..

```
int REQUEST_CODE = 7;
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity2.this, Receiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Activity2.this, REQUEST_CODE, intent, 0);
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setRepeating(am.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), HERE, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: keep in mind that you need to recreate alarms every time the device is restarted, which is all but guaranteed after a year. so you need to create a `BroadcastReceiver` that listens for the `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` action (and you need the `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` permission), and reset the alarm on every boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace 'HERE' with a method that determines if the following February from today is in a leap year, and then returns the value 365 or 366 days (in the form of milliseconds mind you) based on those checks.

```
private long millisUntilNextYear(){

    //Set days in a year for Leap and Regular
    final int daysInLeapYear = 366;
    final int daysInYear = 365;

    //Get calendar instance
    GregorianCalendar cal = (GregorianCalendar) GregorianCalendar.getInstance();

    //Get this year and next year
    int thisYear = cal.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR);
    int nextYear = thisYear + 1;

    //Get today's month
    int thisMonth = cal.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH);

    //Get today's date
    int dayOfMonth = cal.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    //Is today before February? If so then the following February is in THIS year
    if (thisMonth < GregorianCalendar.FEBRUARY){

        //Check if THIS year is leapYear, and return correct days (converted to millis)
        return cal.isLeapYear(thisYear) ? daysToMillis(daysInLeapYear) : daysToMillis(daysInYear);
    }

    //Is today after February? If so then the following February is NEXT year
    else if (thisMonth > GregorianCalendar.FEBRUARY) {
        //Check if NEXT year is leapYear, and return correct days (converted to millis)
        return cal.isLeapYear(nextYear) ? daysToMillis(daysInLeapYear) : daysToMillis(daysInYear);
    }

    //Then today must be February.
    else {
        //Special case: today is February 29
        if (dayOfMonth == 29){
            return daysToMillis(daysInYear);
        } else {
            //Check if THIS year is leapYear, and return correct days (converted to millis)
            return cal.isLeapYear(thisYear) ? daysToMillis(daysInLeapYear) : daysToMillis(daysInYear);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I still can't figure this one out but I know what you mean! Can you explain further or even give me some sample code? @user3829751

Comment: Edited, added code sample for your copy and paste pleasure :)

Answer (score 0):

1) save dates in MM/DD/YY formats.

2) read these dates when you open your app(or at different times)

3) set alerts for single day/today it self.

Plus you can also show birthdays coming in next week/month etc.